Requesting multiple extension for manuscript revision and decision
We have received a major revision for a paper for an Elsevier journal at the end of April this year and initially got the deadline on May 25th.
Due to tight marking deadlines and international travel commitments for my other two coauthors nesseciated an extension which the journal accomodated and granted us until 25th June.
However, we have requested another two weeks extension since one of the authors feel ill. Notwithstanding, we are sanguine that we can still meet the June 25th deadline.
My question is whether multiple requests for extension will by any chance affect the final decision of the paper.

It depends on the journal editor assigned to your paper. Almost exclusively they are also researchers doing the editor work for free in addition to their normal paid activities. Hence, if you satisfactorily explain your need for an extension, he/she will understand... or not, depending on each person. It should not affect the final decision, it would be ridiculous since journals most of the time last months and even years to review a paper.

I'm specialist editor at an Elsevier journal and would never penalize authors for such minor extensions of the revision deadline.
All of the scientific editors (those who usually make these decisions) are themselves (typically senior) scientists and perfectly well understand the constraints (for the similar reasons reviewing may take very long). I would be very surprised if your experience will be different.
